# How can I show (+10 more) if index is greater than value in VUEJS using v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a recipient emailing form in which there could be more than 100 recipients at a time I can only show 9 recipients and I need to add (+10 or whatever remaining recipients are) after showing 9 recipients.

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in recipient" class="app-splitter two-cols">
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>

        <el-button
          style="min-width:20px"
          @click="handleDeleteRecipient(index)"
          icon="el-icon-delete"
          circle
        ></el-button>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Recently I was dealing with the same, but simply computed all I needed in created method or mounted may suite better in your case. Or you can have 2 computed properties. Instead of looping recipients, you will loop computed top10recipients and have another computed morerecipients calculating diff between showing and all

Comment: Do you maybe want [pagination](https://panjiachen.github.io/vue-element-admin-site/feature/component/pagination.html#attributes), since you're using Element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I mentioned in the comment. You can create computed properties like this example and loop just through that. Don't loop all 100 + recipient if not needed ... It might end up with 1000.

```
computed: {
  top10() {
    return this.recipient.slice(0, 10);
  },
  rest() {
    return this.recipient.length - 10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just includ a simple verification like:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in recipient" class="app-splitter two-cols">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>

    <el-button v-if="index < 10"
      style="min-width:20px"
      @click="handleDeleteRecipient(index)"
      icon="el-icon-delete"
      circle
    ></el-button>
```

That v-if will only allow the itens with index lower then 10 to render, i beleive that is what you want at first, but, if you want tha limit to change (like that click at +10 itens) then, create a variable starting at 10 like:

```
data() {
    return {
        limit: 10
    }
}
```

Do you v-if look at it, so change to it:

```
v-if="index < limit"
```

And implement the logic so when the user click at "+10 itens" you incress the limit variable to 20, 30, 40...